# use if else to check if a post value has been selected in a drop down list?

Tags: php, zend-framework, post

How can I fetch a post value from a drop-down list to check if a given value has been selected and use it in a if condition to check if only the element like India is selected then only he should submit. I'm not getting the post values to use if and else condition ?

For example to fetch country I'm using

```
$country = $post['country'];--- how to do this in zend
```

and I want to do some validation like this

```
if($country == 'india) --- how to do this in zend framework

{welcome}
else
{'go to India'}
```

Comment: Why would I want to go to India? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// In your controller
$country = $this->_request->getPost('country'); // Zend-Way to get POST-Data
if($country == 'india')
{
    // It's India
}
else
{
    // Not India
}
```